# why pthread_cond_wait in bionic C is not atomic?

Tags: android, multithreading, posix, libc, bionic

there is race condition in implementation that could allow a signal to be missed. The problem is  pthread_cond_wait function is not atomic? same is discussed in the comment in the file
https://github.com/android/platform_bionic/blob/master/libc/bionic/pthread.c

Shouldn't this operation be atomic ?

Comment: which comment in this file are you talking about? I don't see anything obviously wrong in there...

Comment: please see https://github.com/android/platform_bionic/blob/master/libc/bionic/pthread.c line 1385 the comment says "/* XXX *technically* there is a race condition that could allow
 * XXX a signal to be missed.  If thread A is preempted in _wait()
 * XXX after unlocking the mutex and before waiting, and if other
 * XXX threads call signal or broadcast UINT_MAX/2 times (exactly),
 * XXX before thread A is scheduled again and calls futex_wait(),
 * XXX then the signal will be lost.
 */"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should **not** be worrying about this "race condition". As per the comment, it can only happen if one thread goes to sleep at a pathological place, stays asleep there for a long time, and other threads signal the condition variable a pathological number of times (no more, and no less).

This is actually inherent in many perfectly reasonable low-level implementations of condition variables, especially when based on [futexes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futex). Basically, after the userspace code atomically checks the value of an integer variable, it calls into the kernel to perform a blocking operation, but it instructs the kernel to abort the operation if the value of the integer variable has changed in the meantime. The pathological case is when the integer variable has wrapped all the way around its range an exact integral number of times (while the first caller stayed blocked the whole time!).

If you want to read more than you ever wanted to know about really subtle details like this, read [this paper](http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/futex.pdf).